# basic ajax with external server problem

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to use a yahoo api for place finding and I want to write something like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=701+First+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA&appid=yourappid",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

the yahoo link works properly as you can see here:
http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=701+First+Ave,+Sunnyvale,+CA&appid=yourappid
and the ajax format works if I open a local txt file (this is a w3 example) instead of external link.

but when running this code like that it won't work.
i get:

```
xmlhttp.status==0
```

when

```
xmlhttp.readyState==4
```

and as i found out in another question here it's due to security reasons.
so how do i work around the problem to get the same result?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an external domain you would usually have to do the query on the server and let your ajax call go to your own domain. The server script will query yahoo and return the values for you. How exactly depends on your environment.

Comment: is that what's called cross-domain ajax?

Comment: @tomer That is right. This article might help: http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: yahoo also provides JSON format for that service. so I understand from this article and the refference to the JSON wikipedia article that I can avoid using proxy. is that correct?

Comment: @tomer probably...I have not done that myself but it does seem that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can proxy the response. On your own server, set up a script that simply loads a page from another server and query the page on your server instead of the remote server.